# Get svn info on a deleted file/folder

Tags: svn

I have a bash script that is using the SVN history to create a file list that is used in a deployment script. Today I found a bug that is minor but I would like to fix. However, SVN is not being helpful.

Here is the scenario:

1. commit 1 - a folder and files

   - /trunk/folder/file1
   - /trunk/folder/file2
2. commit 2 - removed the entire folder and all files

   - /trunk/folder

When I am building the file list I am already removing deleted files, but in this case the deleted file is actually a folder. Long story short, I need to determine the type of the svn node that was deleted so I can handle it appropriately.

SVN provides an info command that can tell you this information:

```
svn info TARGET
```

But this does not seem to work with deleted files. In my example above if I try to run info on the deleted folder, I get an error:

```
svn info trunk/folder
```

> svn: warning: W155010: The node 'trunk/folder' was not found.
>
> svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some
>   targets don't exist

If I pass the revision number from the commit when it was deleted, I get the same error:

```
svn info -r2 trunk/folder
```

If I try any multitude of combinations I get the same error:

```
svn info -r1 trunk/folder
svn info -r2 trunk/folder@2
svn info -r1 trunk/folder@2
svn info -r2 trunk/folder@1
```

Is there anyway to get this information on deleted folders?

FYI:
svn, version 1.7.14 (r1542130) compiled Nov 20 2015, 19:25:09

EDIT: This is a simplified explanation of the issue. I'm working with an active repo with 7000 commits and any given issue can be spread across multiple non-consecutive revisions. I'm unable to upgrade the svn version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is your goal and task and why you have to construct the file list manually - Subversion provides `svn list` that you can run also with `--xml` option. If you have direct access to the repository, you could also try `svnlook tree` or `svnlook changed`.

BTW, update your client. SVN 1.7.x is very old; the current version is 1.9.x and you should plan an upgrade.

Comment: I do have direct access to the repo, but the folks using the script that does the work, do not. So svnlook it out. I will look into svn list a little deeper. Thanks.